# Doctrine 1.2: how to get the count of related table rows ina a query?

Tags: count, inner-join, doctrine-1.2

I have a table of users, plus a related table called UserWorkplaces, where one user could have any number of related rows on the UserWorkplaces table.

I'm trying to build a query to find all of the users with only one related row in UserWorkplaces. What kind of query should I use to get this?

Here's what I've tried so far, but it gave me the count of **everyone's** workplaces and only a single user:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Users', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.userWorkplaces uw')
    ->having('COUNT(uw.id) = 1');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is not Doctrine but the SQL you wanna achieve.

Make the story short, following code should work you.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Users u')
    ->innerJoin('u.userWorkplaces uw')
    ->having('COUNT(uw.id) = ?', 1)
    ->groupBy('u.id');
```

COUNT() is aggregate function and therefore you need to specify the GROUP BY parameter for the main table you want to list in.